# React and React Native archetypal model

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

What is a good approach for making a **React** web and a **React Native** app that share their APIs for consuming the same database?
The system will have some CRUD screens for managing products and their images as well diferent events that the user will save. 
I will follow the component / container pattern with Redux to be able to reuse code.
I am working in Windows SO.

---

I was thinking in:

- NodeJs (APIs) and Heroku server
- MongoDB
- React (web app)
- React Native (mobile app)

Are there some common archetypal model when using React and React Native consuming the same apis and DB?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm going to get flamed for this one....Even though it's not persistant to what you asked. I started a new project where we are using Firebase as our cloud backend and it works seamlessly between the web, ios, and android versions (building in react native).
But in regards to your question, react and react-native work well together, You can setup your redux actions (in react-native) almost identical to your react web app. The only differences between how you want to query your backend and handle auth (native uses asyncStorage vs localstorage/cookies). React native has a built in Fetch vs any other React package like Axios or SuperAgent.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't know about Firebase as cloud backend. I was reading a bit and it seems interesting! Do you need a paid plan to have a database and a cloud backend in Firebase? Is your project a big one?

Comment: Firebase is a pay as your scale service. I have less than 30 users(early pre seed) and am still on the free version! It’s pretty cheap when you start comparing it to other scalable hosting. (Heroku/AWS).